Example of a nonlinear system for which the best PID has poor performance
I am looking for a nonlinear system of the form $\dot{x}=f(x, u), y=g(x)$ such that the best
PID has a poor performance.

put in a significant discontinuity and/or delay... or something one-sided like a temp control setup that can't cool nearly as fast as it can heat (although the latter can be made somewhat tolerable with some tweaks)
